# How to create mongodb database collection without adding any data?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm doing a project using MongoDb.my problem is when i create collection, i have to insert data also. but i want to create the collection without data(same as making table in mysql without data.)

Answer (score 6):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/

A quick google would have revealed this.

`db.createCollection("something")`

**Edit**

The PHP method: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.createcollection.php

`$db->createCollection("something");`

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. The OP is asking about how to define the structure of the document before you add data.

Comment: @ScubaSteve this isn't an incomplete answer. You can't define the structure of a document because it's a schemaless database. At least that was the case when I answered this in 2013 anyway.

Comment: I won't be changing the answer, there is enough information for this answer to be correct and complete. OP asked how to create a collection without data, this IS the answer. What you suggested they asked "define the structure of the document before you add data" isn't possible and isn't what they asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer